# how can I create a second instance of the jquery object?

Tags: jquery

I need a second instance of jQuery, or at least of its AJAX facility.
The problem is that I need to contact two servers, and they use different authentication methods.

So in one case I need to set a header:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'Authorization': auth_string
    }
});
```

And not in the other case. If I send headers, the request will fail.

As I need to get data from both servers all the time, I don't want to manipulate the headers before each AJAX call. So it would be nice to use two different AJAX/jQuery objects.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I wonder what would happen if you did `var jq2 = jQuery.extend(true, {}, jQuery);`, as inspired by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object)

Comment: Why dont you just use the url parameter of the ajax call?

Comment: @Utkanos: If I try to use it it says: `it is not an object`.
@Nadir: What do you mean?

Comment: I'll recommend you remove the global config and instanciate two ajax options objects and use them on demand while doing the requests. It will be much simplier.

Comment: @mistic can you post an example as answer

Comment: `$.ajax({url: 'url that needs auth string', headers: { 'Authori...': whatever }}).then(function(result)  { //your handler });`. For the other url, you dont have to add the haeder

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just be able to make two separate settings objects, like so:

`var serverSettings1 = {
    headers: {
        'Authorization': auth_string1
    }
}`

`var serverSettings2 = {
    \\ no headers here
}`

And then pass them in when you make the ajax call: 
`$.ajax(serverSettings1);` or `$.ajax(url, serverSettings2);`
The settings objects can also hold the type of request, url, etc.

(From http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 1):

Following my comment : I suggest not using the global config and use two ajax options object used on demand.

With some factorization it could be :

```
var optionsServerA = {
  headers: {
    'Authorization': auth_string
  }
};

var optionsServerB = {};


// request on server A
$.ajax(
  $.extend({
    url: 'http://servera',
    data: {}
  }, optionsServerA)
)
  .then(...);

// request on server B
$.ajax(
  $.extend({
    url: 'http://serverb',
    data: {}
  }, optionsServerB)
)
  .then(...);
```

And you can create wrappers arround "ajax" for better readability

Comment: I am now using a similar solution. More flexible, I would say.
I have an object, which handles my ajax calls, and this has a property `headers` which can be set similar to my previous function. and when I do the ajax call I use this: `$.ajax({url:...,data:...,headers:self.headers,...})` while self (`var self = this;`) holds the object in my method. still ...  I am waiting for an answer how to create a second instance for some days.